# Creating a second table linked to my first one ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Tags: sql

i am trying to create a second table linked to the one i have just created name Company when i try to add a Foreign Key it doesnt let me

```
CREATE TABLE Weapons (
    id NUMBER(11),
    name VARCHAR2(20),
    damage NUMBER(20),
    company_id NUMBER(11),
    CONSTRAINT pk_Weapons PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Weapons_company FOREIGN KEY(company_id) REFERENCES Company(id),
    );
```

Comment: Probably, you are creating foreign keys referencing a table which doesn't exist yet (maybe an incorrect order in your script?)

Comment: i have created the Company table before i have wrote the Create statement for weapons table

Comment: Then don't you think it would be interesting to include it in the question?

Comment: Creating a SECOND table LINKED to my first one ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
"i am trying to create a second table linked to the one i have just created name Company when i try to add a Foreign Key it doesnt let me"

Comment: Remove the `,`  right before the closing `)`